# Nodejs can't access object member within method

Tags: node.js, oop, ecmascript-6

I'm setting a variable in the constructor and I can't access it from one of the methods as "this" refers to the function (it shouldn't be the case).
Here's what it looks likecode:

```
class myMiddleware {
    constructor(variable) {
        this.variable = variable;
    }
    middleware(packet, next) {
        console.log(this.variable)
    }
}
```

I'm using VS 2017 in case that matters.

EDIT: I'm using this as a socket.io socket middleware.
Here's how I'm doing so :

```
 const myInstance = new myMiddleware(myVariable);
 socket.use(myInstance.middleware);
```

Comment: How are you instantiating the class and calling the method? Works for me.

Comment: `instance.test.bind(instance)`

Comment: @BenFortune edited the question

Comment: @robertklep thank you, it works now! Care to provide me with an explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explaining the solution posted by **robertklep** in the comments:

```
instance.test.bind(instance)
```

Normally when you call a method like this:

```
x.method();
```

the `x` (whatever it is) is bound to `this` when the function `x.method` is called.

If you had a `y` object and did this:

```
y.method = x.method;
```

then when you call:

```
y.method();
```

the `y` would be passed as `this`, not `x`.

It also means then when you do:

```
method = x.method;
```

and try to call:

```
method();
```

the original `x` will not be bound as `this` - and this is your problem here. You were passing the method as a function argument losing the original instance object in the process. The function that you passe your method to couldn't know which object you would like to be bound as `this`.

But all JavaScript functions have method called `.bind()` that returns a function that calls your method with the right object bound as `this`.

So this:

```
let f = x.method.bind(x);
```

makes an `f()` function that is more or less equivalent to:

```
function f(...args) {
  return x.method(...args);
}
```

or:

```
let f = (...a) => x.method(...a);
```

with a difference that you can bind some other object if you want:

```
let f = x.method.bind(y);
```

which would work as if `x`'s `.method()` was called on the `y` object, even if `y` doesn't have such a method.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate explanation :)